# Move file from SD card to app internal data (Storage)

Tags: java, android, file, move

**Background**

I need to take the following file and move it to my apps internal storage.

> *mnt/sdcard/downloads*

I can successfully achieve this by copying the file using the following, then deleting the file from the SD card.

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
writer.write(data);
writer.close();
```

While copying a large file I need double the space (which I don't have).

**Question**

Is it possible to "move" a file (changing the directory) opposed to copy delete

**Other information**
Looking into the matter I've found:

```
public boolean renameTo (File newPath)
```

[doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

> Both paths are on the same mount point. On Android, applications are
>   most likely to hit this restriction when attempting to copy between
>   internal storage and an SD card.
>   [quote taken from here](https://www.sandersdenardi.com/moving-files-in-android/)

I don't know if I can get both paths on the same mount point.

Comment: This gets ugly.  As far as exposed APIs are concerned (even at the unix level where an app userid is concerned), the external storage and the internal storage are separate.  However, your concern about temporarily needing double space suggests that you have one of the more recent devices where the external storage volume is actually emulated on top of the internal storage.  Unfortunately, you probably don't have the ability to leverage that to re-assign those disk blocks without copying the file.

Comment: Thanks Chris this is very useful as I suspected this would be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are dealing with very large files, so you might look into some sort of progressive shrink one/grow the other type of operation - though presumably only if you can detect that there is insufficient space for a full copy.

Comment: Although I doubt I will use progressive shrinking one file/ grow one file. As this will put the files at high risk of becoming corrupt if the application was interrupted (switched off). I believe this is the solution.

Comment: You probably can make it fairly safe, if you make it write a block before removing it, and able to recognize a pair of files from a half-finished transfer.  And of course you should be doing this in a background service, not an activity and not on the UI thread.  The process can still die/crash/be killed, and you should design to recover from that, but it's much less likely that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do the opposite previously (internal to SD, same thing) the copy then delete process is the only one I found to work. I guess it makes sense that you cannot just 'rename' since the files are on different physical storage areas (not sure if the same applies to some 'virtual' SD cards on some Android devices). If they're on different storage spaces, you cannot just swap out the pointers on the file header.

Comment: Thanks for your input simsam7, its good to know I'm not the only one facing these issues.